# Drawing triangles on a slope

Tags: objective-c, math, geometry

I am writing an objective-c method that draws a series of triangles on a slope. In order to complete this, I need to calculate the vertex point of each triangle (C,D). The position starting and ending points are variable.

This seems like it should be an easy math problem. But so far I haven't been able to work it out on paper. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image: triangle problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set triangle at origin horizontally:

   ```
   (0, 0), (p, 0), (p/2, a)
   ```
2. Rotate to get needed slope `alpha`:

   ```
   (0, 0), (p*cos(alpha), p*sin(alpha)), (p/2 * cos(alpha) - a * sin(alpha), p/2 * sin(alpha) + a*sin(alpha))
   ```
3. Shift by adding `(x1, y1)` to all of the coordinates.

The third coordinate is your vertex:

```
(Cx, Cy) = (p/2 * cos(alpha) - a * sin(alpha) + x1, p/2 * sin(alpha) + a*sin(alpha) + y1)
```

To find other vertices use the fact that they are shifted by `p` from each other, under the angle `alpha`:

```
(Cx_i, Cy_i) = (Cx, Cy) + i*(p * cos(alpha), p * sin(alpha))
```

Answer (score 2):

No trigonometry involved.

Let `D= Sqrt(X12^2+Y12^2)` the Euclidean distance between `P1` and `P2` (`X12 = X2-X1` and `Y12 = Y2-Y1`), and let `p= P/D`, `a= A/D`.

If `P1P2` was the line segment `(0, 0)-(1, 0)`, the vertices would be at `(0, 0)`, `(a, p/2)`, `(0, p)`, `(a, 3p/2)`, `(0, 2p)`...

The transform below scales and rotates `(0, 0)-(1, 0)` to `P1P2`:

```
X = X1 + X12.x - Y12.y
Y = Y1 + Y12.x + X12.y
```